# Is there a way to replace None in nested Dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to check if there a way to replace None in nested Dictionary in python. For example, this is the dict in have below

```
dict = {1 : {'Geeks' : [[1, "N", None]], 'Geeks1' : [[1, None, "H"]]}}
```

Can we replace None with 0 here?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show your attempt to do it and we might be able to find the problem of your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
updated_dict = {key: {inner_key: [[x if x is not None else 0 for x in inner_list] for inner_list in inner_value] for inner_key, inner_value in value.items()} for key, value in your_dict.items()}
```

which would print as:

```
{1: {'Geeks': [[1, 'N', 0]], 'Geeks1': [[1, 0, 'H']]}}
```

In general, by using list comprehensions and conditionals, we traverse the nested structure of the dictionary and check each element within the lists. If an element is None, it is replaced with 0.

---

If you wish to do the replacement in-place, then you could try this:

```
your_dict = {1: {'Geeks': [[1, "N", None]], 'Geeks1': [[1, None, "H"]]}}
for inner_list in your_dict.values():
    for lst in inner_list.values():
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            if item is None:
                lst[i] = 0
```

which outputs the same dictionary as the above solution.